# System Config page at backend is showing Blank page

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, admin-panel, system-config, system-configuration

It shows blank page when navigating to System -> Configuration as shown in below image-

[image]

and after changing in 'current configuration scope' dropdown to any website view or store view it shows 404 error on the page like below.

[image]

I don't know why it's happening, may be any module is cause of this or anything else ?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Debug-Hint : Disable module one by one and check which module is cause for this error.

After finding that module check config.xml file 

    <acl></acl>

 tag and check system.xml file and validate it with other module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because some extension you installed lately is incorrectly overriding admin layout/routes.

I had the same issue with "extended google sitemap" extension. Admin was showing 404 if click "**System > Configuration**" dropdown menu.

You see "save config" yellow button in the top right corner? Look in sources/or click it, it will show you where is the issue. (see headers or network tab in browser developers tools)

Also make sure your account have full ACL access rights to every page and module.

Comment: Thanks MagenX, I have used Ultimate SEO module that uses default Google Sitemap, but as there is Extended Google sitemap extension enabled so it overwrite the default Google Sitemap , thats why it causes error.

Comment: Can you know How can I set a page  as default page for System>Configuration>Index page ?

Comment: report the issue to extension developer

Answer (score 0):

1) Clear magento cache.

2) Logout from admin panel and login again.

Comment: Thank for reply still it doesn't work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/91735)

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara in some case this could be answer.

Comment: I don't know that much about but i think this solution works for 404 error only not for blank page

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara This could be wrong answer but this is not comment

Comment: ok will take care next time